# Django-tables2 - How do I disable pagination for a SingleTableMixin,FilterView?

Tags: django, django-views, django-tables2

How can I disable pagination in FilterView?

All the commented out code is what I've already tried. None of which is working.
As soon as I filter the table, the pagination appears at the bottom and part of the filtered result is not visible (unless you go to the next page)

```
class AlpineTableView(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    table_class = AlpineTable
    queryset = Artikel.objects.all()
    filterset_class = AlpineFilter

    # def get_table_pagination(self, request):
    #     return False

    # def get_table_pagination(self, table):
    #     return False

    # table_pagination = False
    # pagination_class = None
    # paginator = None

    # table_pagination = {
    #     "per_page": 100000
    # }

    template_name = "artikelen/alpine-voorraad-filter.html"
```

Comment: Probably something in your template, can you show the code there?

Comment: `table_pagination = False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SingleTableMixin.table_pagination = False

 class AlpineTableView(SingleTableMixin,FilterView): 
    rest of the class
```

This works!